# Push notification from the client

Tags: ios

Can I send a push notification from the client and not from the server ?

The reason I'm asking this is that the port 2195 on my server is blocked.

I would get the token of the receiver device and send the push from the client. Is it feasible ?

thanks

Comment: Why don't use UILocalNotification instead?

Comment: @Evgeniy Shurakov I'm talking about push notifications, which are remote notifications.

Comment: But you want to send them from client? Client is iOS device. Or you want to send from one iOS device to another?

Comment: @Evgeniy Shurakov From one iOS device to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you technically could, but I think it's a very bad idea because you'd need to have the production certificates installed on your users' devices. I would suggest you see if there's an alternative solution, perhaps a third party provider like Urban Airship.

Answer (score 1):

There is a macintosh App called " **Push me baby** " using which you can send the push notifications from the desktop. Search for that . You have to add the certificates etc in that . When you run the app it simply displays a window with two input fields . One for token and another for message . Search on google for "Push me bay mac client app " You will get it. If you don't let me know I will mail you .

Comment: But I actually need a solution for the distribution release, not just for testing.

Comment: Yes you can do that for distribution as well . Its upto you ... If not a huge number would be using the app , its fine. Else you do that . .

Comment: Again if you don't want to setup server side on your own , you can refer to some websites that provide this service, They I guess charge you as per the messages you push.

Comment: Yes, using services like this is a solution, but "Push me baby" can't run, let's say on a unix based VPS I've. You are sating it is a desktop app...